# getTableName not adding table prefix (for 1 table only)

Tags: sql, database, core

We have a prefix in our Magento DB: `prefix_`

Now, Magento has been working fine for years. But in one of the extension when we call the code below. Instead of printing `prefix_catalog_product_index_price` it prints `catalog_product_index_price`. The `prefix_` is missing.

`prefix_catalog_product_index_price` exists in the database just like all the other tables.

```
$adapter = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/resource')->getReadConnection();
Mage::log($adapter->getTableName('catalog_product_index_price'));
```

-

```
$adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
Mage::log($adapter->getTableName('catalog_product_index_price'));
```

What can this be?

Why is `getTableName` not working? or adding the prefix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but for anyone who is searching for the correct answer here it is

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');
```

It will returns "yourtableprefix_customer_entity"

Answer (score 2):

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection->getTableName('catalog/product_index_price')
```

In *Catalog module* `config.xml` Magento define this table entity is  `product_index_price`

```
 <product_index_price>
     <table>catalog_product_index_price</table>
 </product_index_price>
```

for getting a table with prefix then try

**`$adapter->getTable('yourmodelprefix/entities');`**